# How i can pass image.file() to list of images

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

i'm learning flutter ,can anyone help me how i can pass ImageFileList to image.file widget or if someone has any other suggestion please comemnt it really relp me.Using gridVeiw builder to preview images

```
final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
      List<XFile> imageFileList = [];

  void selectedImage() async {
    final List<XFile> selectedImage = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
    if (selectedImage.isNotEmpty) {
      imageFileList.addAll(selectedImage);
    }
  }

  Image.file()//here
```

Comment: are you want to show all the images that are stored in imageFileList?

Comment: yes i want multiple images that store in file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use index and this converter:

```
Image.file(File(imageFileList[1].path))
```

you can use it `ListView` like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Image.file(File(imageFileList[index].path));
    },
    itemCount: imageFileList.length,
  )
```

also remember `import 'dart:io'` not `import 'dart:html'`;

Comment: already try this but gives me a error {2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments} Actually File take File(filebit,fileName)

Comment: @HassanNaveed you were import wrong File, you need import 'dart:io' not the one with 'dart:html'.

Comment: yes you are rigth thanks buddy